# Is this an example of DTO or ...?

Tags: design-patterns, immutability, dto, proxy-classes

I've worked on several projects where we very strictly code to interfaces which expose little or no mutability for the interface properties.  Then, I find myself writing classes which provide arbitrary ability to mutate the object in any way and return it.

Here's an example:

```
public interface IOlapCube
{
  String CubeName {get;}
  IEnumerable<IDimension> Dimensions{get;}
  IEnumerable<IMeasure> Measures {get;}
  IEnumerable<IMeasureGroup> MeasureGroups {get;}
}

public class OlapCubeRW : IOlapCube
{
  public String CubeName {get;set;}
  private List<IDimension> _dimensionList;
  public IList<IDimension> Dimensions{get{return this._dimensionList;}}
  IEnumerable<IDimension> IOlapCube.Dimensions{get{return this.Dimensions;}}

  //... similar for the rest
}
```

Is this a DTO?  Where should I define this class?  Should it be in the same assembly as the IOlap cube?  And if so, should it be in the same name space?  I'm finding that several projects which use the IOlapCube could benefit from the RW class, and I hate reimplementing internal classes which are identical in each project.  these classes are also useful for unit testing where I can create any arbitrary derived class and refer to it by interface.  Eg, for each interface there is an associated IEqualityComparer and unit testing the comparer is fairly simply when I can construct two objects with any shape I desire and compare them.

These are also used typically for editing entities.  I can pass an entity to a form, and have it copy into one of these objects.  Then the form can arbitrarily alter the object, and I can validate it with an external class like bool OlapCubeValidator.IsValid(IOlapCube cubeToValidate); and copy the changes back into an entity if validation passes (perhaps entity proxy over this RW class which is now ensured valid).

It feels wrong to put them in the same location as the IOlap only because it seems that clients shouldn't spin up one of these and use it, but I suppose it doesn't hurt anything if I can perform validation externally.  This specific project is internal to the company so we don't really have to worry about malice, just lazy programming.  Would it change anything if this was a publicly available library?

**EDIT**
It is important to note that this interface hierarchy (IOlapCube > IDimension, IMeasureGroup, IMeasure > IHierarchy > ILevel > IMember) exposes no methods or other functionality; they only provide data (such as names, children objects, IsVisible, ...).  There are **no** methods like IQueryable(T) ExecuteQuery(T)(ICriteria(T) criteria).  The validation and equality definitions are part of external interfaces (eg, IEqualityComparer).

Comment: [Yes/no questions about an example are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions). Answers to such questions are rarely useful to anyone except the original asker. The purpose of this site is to create a useful repository of high quality questions with answers. Instead of asking "is this an example of _X_", ask "what is _X_".

Answer (score 0):

As long as DTO is being used to hold data only (no business logic), it wouldn't matter if you keep the interface in the same assembly or different assembly.